# Problem with displaying errors on login form using sessions

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session

I have login form in Laravel and I am having trouble displaying errors on my email and password fields. I made validator in which I have that error message and I put it in session and redirected it on GET /login. I need help on how to read those values from session and return them in blade as parameter and then to be able to display those error messages for email and password. Currently validation works but it displays no messages, it only redirects back to login page. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

web.php

```
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
```

LoginController

```
public function showLoginForm(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->session()->get('data');

    return view('auth.login', compact('session'));
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $rules = array(
        'email'    => 'required|email', 
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $request->session()->put('data', $request->input());
        return redirect()->intended('login')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput($request->session()->put('data', $request->input()));
    } else {
        $userData = array(
            'email'     => $request->get('email'),
            'password'  => $request->get('password')
        );
    }
    
    if (Auth::attempt($userData)) {
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    } else {        
        redirect()->intended('login');
    }
}
```

login blade

```
<div class="login-page">
        <div class="login-box">
            <div class="card mb-0">
                <div class="card-body login-card-body">
                    <p class="login-box-msg font-weight-bold">Sign in to start your session</p>
                    <form method="POST" class="mb-4" action="{{route('login') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <div class="input-group-text">
                                    <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @error('email')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" autocomplete="current-password">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <div class="input-group-text">
                                    <span class="fas fa-eye-slash cursor-pointer" style="display: none" onclick="showPassword()"></span>
                                    <span class="fas fa-eye cursor-pointer" onclick="showPassword()"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @error('password')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="float-right">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block font-weight-bold">Sign In</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to call `->withErrors($validator->errors())`. This returns the correct `MessageBag`. Otherwise you are returning a `Validator` instance.
Afterwards you can use the `$errors` variable or the `@error` tag as intended.

@edit
insted of `inteded()` use `route()` or `back()`.

Comment: Ok, I added this in my controller, but it still is the same, no messages is shown.

Comment: I put it with just ->withInput() still the same. And what do you mean 'flashing to the session'?

Comment: what is the idea behind using `->intended()`, maybe you will need to call `->route()` instead. 
Can you dd($errors) in your view?

I talked about ` $request->session()->put('data', $request->input());` this part is not needed in my opinion.

Comment: @mrmar instead of intended() I would siply redirect them back()

Comment: yeah. when O put route('login') now it works. Great. Put it as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Also one small thing if you have time. How can I check my password if it is the same password as in database? Currently with this when I make error in email it also show me error in password and I want it to be separate

Comment: @mrmar sorry I didn't see it before. Assuming that your email is unique you first have to get the row where the $request->email is. `$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first()`.  You can then check it by using: `Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)`

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/hashing