# How to validate password to check if it is the same password as in database?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have login form in Laravel that uses email and password to log on site. I have all validation and everything works fine except for password. When I type wrong password it goes to blank page and I want to write some error beneath password field. I looked in same:password validation but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

LoginController.php

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'email'    => 'required|email|exists:App\User,email', 
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:5'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $request->session()->put('data', $request->input());
        return redirect()->route('login')
            ->withErrors($validator->errors())
            ->withInput($request->session()->put('data', $request->input()));
    } else {
        $userData = array(
            'email'     => $request->get('email'),
            'password'  => $request->get('password')
        );
    }
    
    if (Auth::attempt($userData)) {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    } else {        
        redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

login.blade.php

```
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="login-box">
        <div class="card mb-0">
            <div class="card-body login-card-body">
                <p class="login-box-msg font-weight-bold">Sign in to start your session</p>
                <form method="POST" class="mb-4" action="{{route('login') }}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @error('email')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-eye-slash cursor-pointer" style="display: none" onclick="showPassword()"></span>
                                <span class="fas fa-eye cursor-pointer" onclick="showPassword()"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @error('password')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="float-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block font-weight-bold">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your login view too?

Comment: @Unflux Here it is

Comment: You need to hash password before storing.

Comment: why are you trying to validate the password against the database in the first place?  just so you can know if they failed the login because of 'email' or 'password'?

Comment: @lagbox Yes, that is correct.

Comment: so now an attacker will know that an email address exists (is real) and can now focus on the password   ;-)  but that may or may not be a worry for you, just pointing that out

Comment: I didn't think of that :)

Comment: @lagbox yes but with this code, if user just enters wrong password it shows blank page not some error

Comment: @lagbox which else do you mean?

Comment: @lagbox Yeah now it redirects back on login page but doesn't show any error it just redirects it

Comment: because you are not returning the errors .. you are building the response yourself so you have to deal with passing the errors with it

Comment: @lagbox I passed them but still it just redirects no messages

Comment: @lagbox Can you help in example?

Comment: i am a bit confused , you asked a quesation about the same code as: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63301737/problem-with-displaying-errors-on-login-form-using-sessions/63302173#63302173

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your email is `unique`, you first have to get the DB row where the `$request->email` is: `$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first()`

You can then check it by using: `Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)`

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/hashing

@edit

To add it to the rules you will have to create a Rule Class: `php artisan make:rule myRuleName`
Afterwards you will call it like that:

```
$rules = [
        'email'    => 'required|email|exists:App\User,email', 
        'password' => ['required','alphaNum','min:5', new myRuleName()],
    ];
```

In your custom Rule Class you will find a `passes($attribute, $value)`function.
Now you can insert the code i wrote above into this method. You will have to replace `$request->password` with `$value`

Comment: I am having trouble with writing the code. How should I add this to the $rules variable?

Comment: I get only redirect to login page no message

Comment: I am not sure why the error is not displayed. But you will need to post another question because it is another problem.

Comment: I will in a minute